# Visual Studio 2019 QuickWatch displays Unable to evaluate (Unable to evaluate) in ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly Program.cs File

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to debug and evaluate expression in my `blazor wasm` `Program.cs` using `QuickWatch` in my `Visual Studio 2019`. To make the breakpoint hit in `Main` method, I added

```cs
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

this gives debugging proxy some time to load as mentioned in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#breakpoints-in-oninitializedasync-not-hit).

Now after my break point gets hit if I select any expression and press `Shift+F9` to toggle `QuickWatch`, I get

> Unable to evaluate (Unable to evaluate)

for any variables, expression. Please assist on what I'm missing

**Screen Print:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently Blazor WebAssembly does not support hitting breakpoint the `Program > Main` method inside `Program.cs`. Below is from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio):

> For now, you *can't*:
>
> - Break on unhandled exceptions.
> - Hit breakpoints during app startup before the debug proxy is running. This includes breakpoints in
>   `Program.Main (Program.cs)` and breakpoints in the
>   `OnInitialized{Async}` methods of components that are loaded by the
>   first page requested from the app.

Comment: adding `await Task.Delay(10000);` in `Main` makes the break point to hit in `Program.cs` but unable to evaluate the expression in `QuickWatch`

Comment: Yes you are right, I tried this and was unable to see the values in quickwatch window, neither in the immediate window. I will try to find a solution and get back if I am successful.

Comment: Thanks. Keep it posted. I'll post an answer if I find any.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was an upgrade issue from DotNet Core 3.x to 5.0.

It is a good idea to create a completely new Blazor Application with identical configuration and compare all project files. In my case it was an entry in {MyProject}.Server.csproj of:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="3.2.1" />
```

that needed to be updated to the latest version:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="5.0.4" />
```

Everything worked fine to run and breakpoints were hit but until I changed that line all variables would show "Unable to evaluate (Unable to evaluate)" in Quickwatch and hovering in the editor showed nothing.